# Make CSS background-position reference an image from right to left

Tags: css, css-sprites

I know the typical way to use a sprite with background-position is to reference the images in the sprite using the upper left hand corner and provide negative coordinates. I have a rounded rectangle that I am using for buttons and I want to provide the coordinate for the upper right hand corner of the rectangle and and have it repeat-x to the left of the right edge of the triangle. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

From what I think you are asking, it sounds like you want to use this rule:

```
background-position: 100% 0;
```

or

```
background: url(image.png) repeat-x 100% 0;
```

That should push the background image over so that is matches up with the right side of whatever element it is in.